# Parse Client Push Notifications Not Working

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to set up push notifications for my new app. I am getting the following error from Parse. Is everyone having the same issue? Is there a work around it?

Push notification is working for my other apps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok - This is weird I was able to fix it by changing the name of my app. Not sure why this worked, but it worked.

Comment: This worked for me too... I have no idea why?  Also, Parse wasn't letting me upload an Icon for my app, but after changing the name it let me.

Comment: I was getting {
code: 2,
error: "the request took too long to process"
} when I tried to upload an icon before changing the name.